# The usage of »Du bist willkommen«?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

Is it ok to use

> Du bist willkommen.

in the sense of

> Thank you, you are welcome.

If not, what should I use in this context?

Comment: The word »willkommen« is not a noun and therefore must not be written with uppercase first letter (except if it is the first word of a sentence). I corrected this for you in the title of your question.

Comment: Thank you @HubertSchölnast. I have a question, have you tried out the Duolingo app on windows platform? I am learning bits and pieces of german in this app.

Comment: I am a German native speaker, so I don't need any apps to learn German. And I am using a Macbook and an iMac for many years. I also have a server for my website and to host the websites of my customers, but this is Linux. Sorry, I don't use any Microsoft products except Excel and Word (the Mac-Versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a little bit tricky for english natives.

"Du bist willkommen" means just "Welcome".

If you want answer to " thank you", you can just say "kein Problem" (no problem) oder "gerne".
If you want to be very formal, you can say "Das Vergnügen war ganz auf meiner Seite" (The pleasure was on my side)

Comment: Gesundheit. – Danke. – Das Vergnügen war ganz auf meiner Seite.

Comment: @dakab, nein,  das geht so nicht.

Comment: @Iris: Sehe ich auch so. Die Antwort suggeriert aber, dass das eine allgemeingültige Replik für »Danke« ist.

Comment: @dakab, ah. Dann solltest du das aber bitte direkter schreiben, weil gerade Nichtmuttersprachler (und ich) die Ironie schwer erkennen.

Comment: The last sentence is a special case. That should be clarified in the answer: "Es hat mich gefreut mich sie kennen zu lernen." (="It was a pleasure to meet you")-  "Das Vergnügen war ganz auf meiner Seite" (="The pleasure was mine!")

Answer (score 4):

While “you’re welcome” is entirely natural in English, a literal translation to German would mean something like “I bid thee welcome” or “You are a welcomed guest”. Did you mean that? It’s a nice, unusual thing to say.

For the standard dialogue, there are other options:

> “Thank you.”—“You are welcome.”
>
> »Danke dir.« – »Gern geschehen.« (or *bitte sehr* or simply *gerne* or …)

Answer (score 3):

"You're welcome" in Englisch, als Antwort auf ein "Dankeschön" und "Sie sind willkommen" in Deutsch haben völlig verschiedene Bedeutung.

"You're welcome" ist nur eine Floskel um anzudeuten dass das Dankeschön nicht notwendig war. In Deutsch würde man zum Beispiel sagen "Gern geschehen", oder "kein Problem", je nach Situation und individueller Sprachweise.

"Sie sind willkommen" bedeutet "Ich bin froh, dass sie hier anwesend sind". Das sagt man zum Beispiel wenn Gäste ankommen, die man gerne sieht.